# How to get the Sequence name using yaml-cpp

Tags: c++, yaml-cpp

Refering to this question [yaml-cpp read sequence in item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31368135/yaml-cpp-read-sequence-in-item)

If the yaml looks like

```
sensors:
  - id1:
      hardwareId: 28-000005a32133
      type: 1
  - id2:
      hardwareId: 28-000005a32132
      type: 4
```

How to get the name of the sequence from the node ?
Using the sensors node how can i get the names of id1 and id2 ?

Answer (score 2):

Just iterate through the node; you get key/value pairs:

```
for (const auto& kv : node["sensors"]) {
  kv.first.as<std::string>();  // "id1" or "id2"
}
```

Comment: terminate called after throwing an instance of 'YAML::InvalidNode'
  what():  invalid node; this may result from using a map iterator as a sequence iterator, or vice-versa